# Scales with free locations but fixed scaling in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, facet

Is it possible within `facet_wrap` or `facet_grid` to free the location of a scale  but fix the *scaling* (i.e. the distance between tick marks)?

The `fixed` option both fixes the location and scale of a given scale. E.g., below, each pane has the same limits and scaling:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(within(mtcars, 
              split <- rowSums(sapply(c(.3,.5,.6),function(x) disp> quantile(disp,x))%*%(1:3))),
       aes(mpg, hp)) + geom_point() + stat_smooth(method='lm', se=F) + 
  facet_wrap(~split, scales = 'fixed')
```

[image: fixed]

On the other hand, the `free` optional allows both the location and scaling to vary across panes:

```
ggplot(within(mtcars, 
              split <- rowSums(sapply(c(.3,.5,.6),function(x) disp> quantile(disp,x))%*%(1:3))),
       aes(mpg, hp)) + geom_point() + stat_smooth(method='lm', se=F) + 
  facet_wrap(~split, scales = 'free_y')
```

[image: free]

Is it possible to allow center of the scale to vary but to fix the distance between tick marks? In the above example, this would correspond to having each scale centered at the mean y value of the pane but fixing the distance between tick marks to 50. Note that this cannot be addressed using the `space` or `aspect.ratio` options.

Comment: I think the answer is "Yes, it's possible", but you need to work at a low level.  See https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/vignettes/extending-ggplot2.html .  You will need to change the `train_scales` method in a `FacetWrap` descendant type.

Comment: @Richard: you can also consider making 4 separate panels then merge them together if it's not too much work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any option to do this directly within the faceting system, (unless you delve deeply into custom faceting) but it's easily achieved with the old "invisible box" trick. Basically you just ensure each panel has an invisible box drawn a fixed value above and below the group y-mean, and a fixed distance on either side of the x-mean:

```r
ggplot(within(mtcars, {
              split <- rowSums(sapply(c(.3,.5,.6), 
                                      function(x) disp > quantile(disp, x)) %*% (1:3));
              mins <- ave(hp, split) - 100;
              maxs <- ave(hp, split) + 100;
              minx <- ave(mpg, split) -8;
              maxx <- ave(mpg, split) +8;
              }), 
       aes(mpg, hp)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = minx, xmax = maxx, ymin = mins, ymax = maxs), 
            alpha = 0, colour = "#00000000") +
  stat_smooth(method='lm', se=F) + 
  facet_wrap(~split, scales = 'free')
```

[image]

You can see the size of the scale is the same on all 4 plots but each cluster of dots is centered with its x-mean and y-mean at the mid-point of the plot.

Comment: Aha, that's a clever hack and will definitely solve my problem for the time being. I suspect there's likely a way to do without the invisible box as suggested by @user2554330, but it's probably low level and more trouble than it's worth for a one off application.

Comment: @RichardBorder that's true. I think I would avoid that unless writing a package or maybe producing a regular report.